# Can I say "This is the best song from Chris Brown." instead of "This is the best song by Chris Brown."?

Tags: word-usage

When I say **"This is the best song from Chris Brown."** instead of **"This is the best song by Chris Brown."**, it sounds kind of wrong to me. Can I use "from" instead of "by" in that sentence? I know that "by" is correct there but I wonder if "from" is also correct. I think native speakers can use it but I wonder about your opinions. If I used "from" there, would it sound awkward?

Comment: The best song [to come] from Chris Brown this year was x. Sure, it's fine.

Comment: The best song **by** Chris Brown could imply it is a song that he wrote.

Comment: He could have written it, and **from** would still be OK.   **by** casts him as the song-maker; **from** casts him as a song-source.

Comment: Either is fine; "by" is probably a little more common.  And you most definitely can use "by" for a song that was performed by Chris Brown, even if he didn't write it.  In fact that's probably the most common usage in this context since most artists you hear on the radio don't write their own songs.

Comment: Radio DJs frequently say **from** where I'm from.

Comment: I think "from" basically implies a talent performance (with all that goes into it), while "by" implies he wrote it. But pretty much interchangeable without some context, and not awkward either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can say that. It's very common to hear presenters or DJs use **from** in this context.